# Console history single command length limit

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I've come to notice, that long multi line commands are not logged to the `ConsoleHost_history.txt` in PowerShell 7 (unlike in PowerShell 5). How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `AddToHistoryHandler` of `Get-PSReadLineOption` is `$null` in PowerShell 5, in PowerShell 7 it isn't.

Executing the following removes the handler and long multi line commands are logged as well:

```powershell
Set-PSReadLineOption -AddToHistoryHandler $null
```

To make this change permanent, add the line above to your PowerShell 7 profile. The location of the profile file is stored in the automatic variable `$PROFILE` (you might need to create the file).